# Why is the Wasserstein distance between [0, 1] and [1, 0] zero?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

Isn't the Wasserstein distance supposed to be a non-zero number since the probabilities are not equivalent?

```
In [1]: scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance([0, 1], [1, 0])
Out[1]: 0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because

```
scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance
```

expects 1D distributions in the first and second argument. It doesn't matter in which order you obtained the (same) observations, the distribution is the same.
Check that for instance

```
scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance([3, 1, 2, 4, 5], [1 ,4 ,5 ,3 ,2])
```

is also

```
0.0
```

for the same reason.

Comment: Is there a metric that would see those two arrays as different observations? (as order is important)

Comment: You could calculate Wasserstein-distance in each coordinates separately (as separate 1D distributions), I am not sure if it'd make sense in your problem.