# Wasserstein distance in scipy - definition of support

Tags: python, scipy.stats

I want to use the Wasserstein distance from scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance to get a measure for the difference between two probability distribution. However, I do not understand how the support matters here.

For example, I would have expected
`stats.wasserstein_distance([0,1,0],[1,0,0])`
to be 1 (as we need to move a mass of weight 1 by a distance of 1), however it is 0. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[Why is the Wasserstein distance between [0, 1] and [1, 0] zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57402842/why-is-the-wasserstein-distance-between-0-1-and-1-0-zero)

In short, the Wasserstein distance in scipy is for „1d distributions“; this means that if I have a probability distribution P(A) where a has three states that are observed with probabilities p(a1)=1, p(a2)=p(a3)=0, and another probability distribution P(B), where b has three states that are observed with probabilities p(b1)=p(b3)=0 and p(b2)=1, and want the earth movers distance between these two distributions, the scope Wasserstein distance is NOT the right object for this.

Edit:
I found the answer somewhere; the right implementation here is to use the weights as the probability distribution and uvalues and vvalues as the support, i.e.
`stats.wasserstein_distance(np.arange(3), np.arange(3), [1,0,0],[0,1,0])`
which gives 1, as expected.

Comment: Do you think that it would work just fine for continuous variables? We could define supports as the values that were sampled from the distributions. The weights would be probability density function values at the sample points